# Most perfomance way to get user scroll position on scroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

What is the best-performance way to get window.scroll position when user scrolls the page?
Maybe when the event fires there  is some variable witch natively store something like $(window).scrollTop() value and there is no need to call $(window).scrollTop() manually to figure it out?

Comment: Why would you need this? Can you not just call `$(window).scrollTop()`?

Comment: are you talking about binding an event listener and fire `scrollTop` on that event.

Comment: What difference would that make?

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'm trying to figure out the best (in performance) way to get user scroll position when  window.onscroll event triggers. I'll try to write my thoughts more clearly next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the scroll via the $(this) keyword.
So you'd do something like this:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var scroll = $(this)[0].scrollY
});
```

That's your alternative. I didn't do any tests to see whether it's better performance wise, but it's an option if you do not want to call the $(window).scrollTop()